# Boolean: How to convert a NAND4 to a NAND2

Tags: boolean, boolean-logic, boolean-expression, boolean-operations

I have the following problem. My equation is:

```
NAND2(NAND4(d,c,-b,a),NAND2(c,-a))
```

the `"-"` represents `"NOT"`. I am not allowed to use `NAND4`, I am only allowed to use `NAND2`.

How do I convert this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `NAND` in general is equivalent to `NOT(AND(…))`
- `AND4(a, b, c, d)` is equivalent to `AND2(AND2(a, b), AND2(c, d))`
- `NAND4(a, b, c, d)` is thus equivalent to `NOT(AND4(a, b, c, d))` and that’s equivalent to `NOT(AND2(AND2(a, b), AND2(c, d)))`
- This is equivalent to `NAND2(AND2(a, b), AND2(c, d))`
- If you were only allowed to use NANDs but not ANDs, you could invert the ANDs there: `NAND2(NOT(NAND2(a, b)), NOT(NAND2(c, d)))`